# Domain Failing Checks at JustPing, Downforeveryoneorjustme, Pingdom, etc

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, nameserver

My website www.animedokidoki.com seems to be failing a bunch of online check sites, such as

http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/animedokidoki.com

http://www.just-ping.com/index.php?vh=animedokidoki.com

http://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.animedokidoki.com

http://tools.pingdom.com/?url=www.animedokidoki.com

Any ideas why this is happening? Is my domain not set up properly? the dns, nameservers, etc, or maybe this is a firewall issue.

It is run on Linux w/ apache and Webmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your name servers are screwed up.

```
dmourati$ dig -t ns animedokidoki.com

; <<>> DiG 9.4.3-P3 <<>> -t ns animedokidoki.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5673
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;animedokidoki.com.     IN  NS

;; ANSWER SECTION:
animedokidoki.com.  38400   IN  NS  ns1.animedokidoki.com.
animedokidoki.com.  38400   IN  NS  ns2.animedokidoki.com.

;; Query time: 267 msec
;; SERVER: 68.87.76.182#53(68.87.76.182)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun 11 17:18:11 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 71
```

You need to have  [glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) to tell other DNS servers where to find ns1/ns2.  Have you made recent changes with your registrar?

Comment: can you please check if I fixed the issue?

Comment: Looks good: http://check-host.net/check-http?host=www.animedokidoki.com

Answer (score 1):

```
$ dig +trace +short animedokidoki.com
...
dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.animedokidoki.com': not found
```

When I do a whois:

```
Name Servers:
   NS1.ANIMEDOKIDOKI.COM
   NS2.ANIMEDOKIDOKI.COM
```

When I try looking up these nameservers, I get no results. Looks like you have your domain pointed at so-called custom/branded nameservers, but you don't have ["glue records"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records) setup for ns1.animedokidoki.com and ns2.animedokidoki.com.

You need glue records pointing straight at the nameserver IPs, because your nameservers are a subdomain of the domain you're trying to resolve. This is a circular reference. In this case, your website is animedokidoki.com, and the nameservers are the subdomains ns1 and ns2. Glue records fix the circular reference problem.

### now:

```
$ dig +short animedokidoki.com ns1.animedokidoki.com ns2.animedokidoki.com
217.23.4.156
217.23.4.156
217.23.4.156
```

Comment: can you please check if I fixed the issue?

Comment: looks like you're using the same IP for your nameservers and website, which isn't always the best thing - but it resolves :) check the "now" section of my answer.